# Why pimcore folder isn't ignored and managed by composer

Tags: pimcore

Why `pimcore` directory in project root isn't git ignored?
According documentantion :

> /pimcore/ Core files of Pimcore, do not change anything here.

We shouldn't change anything here. Why this catalog is not managed by composer?

Comment: What version of Pimcore you're using? How did you install it, from build package or composer?

Comment: 4.6.0 version installed through composer create project

Answer (score 1):

How composer installs project is a decision made by Pimcore Core Team. On the other hand, how to handle .gitignore is up to you.

Personally, keeping core files in repository makes deployments, updates and tracking changes easier for me.

Pimcore folder is not managed by composer, because of update system in Pimcore - updating code is not enough, there are also changes in database. Recommended way of updating core is to use Pimcore's built-in commands.

Comment: I don't get it. 
Maybe it got sense in 4.6.0 when project was based on zend framework, but now in SF3 is not good solution. Why I have to keep these files in my repository which I won't change... 
It is also protection from lazy developers to change somthing in base code directly.
There is many possibilities to handle db migration, I don't think it's problem to handle it from vendor